# Comparing strings and Inserting values based on comparison in JS

Tags: javascript

Here is the scenario 
I am getting a value from user which I have to parse to float by rounding it up to a certain decimal point but user value can contain `","` I need to put , at same place where it was in user value for example if user entered `+55,658,698.2396` and value is to be parsed to 2 decimal points the output should be `+55,658,698.24` but after parsing I get `+55658698.24`
Here is the sample code

```
var userInput = "+54,568,568.14589";
var decimalPoints = 3;
var convertedValue;

var indexP = userInput.indexOf("+");
//getting rid of commas
var value = userInput.replace(/,/g , "");

value =parseFloat(value).toFixed(decimalPoints);
convertedValue = value.toString(); 
if(indexP == 0){
console.log('Converted Value: +'+convertedValue);
}
else{
console.log('Converted Value: '+convertedValue);
}
console.log('Actual Value: '+userInput);
```

and Here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k5jhha4r/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951738/culture-sensitive-parsefloat-function-in-javascript