# how to replace multiple special character in a number?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a number say 2,500.00 and i want to convert the number into 2.500,00. So, we can replace the special character using replace like

```
var x = 2,500.00; 
x.replace(/,/g,".");
```

and for "Dot" also, we can do it. But in this case, it won't work because when we apply replace function for comma as above, the number will become 2.500.00 and if we apply now, it will become as 2,500,00.

So is there any way to convert 2,500.00 into 2.500,00 ?

Comment: Replace to something else first, like a `*`. For instance `,` -> `*`, then `.` -> `,` and finally `*` -> `.`.

Comment: Thanks for your help evolutionbox, but its a kind of workaround i think so. Is there any straight method for this?

Comment: There is no direct function that is cross browser compatible (not IE11+).

Comment: If you're working with numbers you can also use http://numeraljs.com to parse and reformat numbers.

Comment: `var x = 2,500.00` is a syntax error.

Comment: What about [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951738/culture-sensitive-parsefloat-function-in-javascript)? Does it help?

Comment: thanks for the post stribizhev. But its not working in my case, but learned something in that post.

Comment: @KingMob seems to have a really nice solution for any number of dots and commas. The currently accepted anubhava solution works only for the specific case where there's one dot and no commas after the dot. Otherwise, it fails.

Comment: @ChisholmKyle Actually in my case, its a number, so this solution will work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
var x = '2,123,500.00'; 
var arr = x.split('.');
var y = arr[0].replace(/,/g, '.') + ',' + arr[1];
//=> 2.123.500,00
```

Comment: This solution works for the specific case where there's one dot and no commas after the dot. Otherwise, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: There is indeed only one dot in input as per OP.

Answer (score 3):

[String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can take a function:

```
'2,123,500.00'.replace(/[,.]/g, function(c){ return c===',' ? '.' : ','; });
```

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Oh. Where?

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken (and learned something new). I though the `.` would match every characters...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon It does match every character, but not when it's inside a character class. The character class matches stuff _literally_. See here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special

Comment: @Pluto That's not entirely true, e.g. \s in a character class still matches whitespace.

Comment: Of course it does, that's why I linked to the other document for further explanation.

Comment: King Mob : I have a small doubt. Here, what c is actually. Why it is used in the statement?

Comment: @Thinker It's the matched character which is passed to the replacement function. You could rename it to `match` if that's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck, `.replace()` accept a function as second argument. That function has the matched string as argument and the returned value will be the `replace_by` value of `.replace()`.

In short, you can simply check what the matched string is and return the right value :

```js
var str = "2,500.00";

var changed_str =  str.replace(/,|\./g, function(old){
    if (old === '.')
        return ',';
    else if (old === ',')
        return '.';
});


document.write(changed_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built-in methods to format your numbers correctly?

[`Number.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) would work just fine here.

If you actually have a number as you said, you can easily achieve this using the right locale. If you have a String representation of your number, you would first have to parse it.

Comment: Only thing to note is the browser compatibility. It's an IE11+ only solution. It doesn't even work in Safari.

Answer (score -1):

This (now) works for any number of commas or dots, even if trailing or leading dots or commas.

HTML:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS:

```
var x = '.,2.123,50.0.00.';

var between_dots = x.split('.');
for (var i = 0; i < between_dots.length; i++) {
    between_dots[i] = between_dots[i].replace(/,/g, '.');
}
var y = between_dots.join(',');

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = y;
```

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6zmcd8k/4/)