# Using toLocaleString to en-US

Tags: javascript

So I am looking at the following functionality https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString . In all the examples, its taking a US formatted number and going to another locale. Is there a way to go from another locale to US?

Example

`9 000` 
to
`9000`

OR

`99,99`
to
`99.99`

Yes I can remove the space with regex, but there are other locale specific stuff I want to convert. Thanks

Comment: "In all the examples, its taking a US formatted number and going to another locale." You're mistaken. In all the example, it's taking *a JavaScript number* and formatting it per some locale. What you're really asking is how to parse a string given a particular locale, which has been asked before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Culture sensitive ParseFloat Function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951738/culture-sensitive-parsefloat-function-in-javascript)

Comment: `toLocaleString` is for formatting, but your question is about parsing. Consider improving the text of your question. The examples are not parsing en-US, they are all using literal numbers.

Comment: @JordanRunning That question doesn't have very good answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert String to Number according to locale (opposite of .toLocaleString)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645163/how-do-i-convert-string-to-number-according-to-locale-opposite-of-tolocalestri)

Comment: Sounds like you have to either pick a library that does this ([globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize), [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/), [parse-decimal-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-decimal-number)) or roll your own as in the answers suggested by Jordan.